# JQuery, CSS - many a href links but one action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Resolved, thanks for help, it works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/c3AeN/1/ by Sudharsan

I have a lot of links on my page and all of them have format like this:
edit: format 'like this' means that all links have the same class and only diffrent id and text.

```
$(".do_it").click(function(){
 // here I get id from link and go to chosen site
}

<a href="#" class="do_it" id="999">link1</a>
<a href="#" class="do_it" id="998">link2</a>
.
.
.

<a href="#" class="do_it" id="1">link999</a>
```

there is of-course some action depends on id and the problem is when user click on one, all became purple. Is there any easy solution to make only purple this one what what clicked? 
//Sry for my eng

Comment: Unable to understand the question.Please post the code

Comment: -1 This is a terrible question, what does "format like this: link1 link2 . . ." mean for starters?

Comment: At lease provide link to the website if you can't describe question properly.

Comment: what is the value for "href" attribute? Provide different values for each

Comment: `a:active` or `a:visited` or `a:hover` could be used. Provide your html and css code for a better understanding to anser the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, make the links (visited) the same color as the link.

```
a {
    color: #00f;
}
a:visited {
    color: #00f;
}
.visitedLink {
    color: #f00; /* your color */
}
```

Create a class with the color desired, and in the jQuery, on the clicked one, add that class:

```
$(".mylink").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("visitedLink");
    //do rest of code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a different `href` each link:

```
<a href="#1">1</a><br>
<a href="#2">2</a><br>
<a href="#3">3</a><br>
<a href="#4">4</a><br>
```

EDIT: don't have the onclick handler return false, otherwise the link is not actually visited. But this means that if the user has scrolled, it will reset to the top of the page upon each click.

Comment: This is the best answer as all the other CSS solutions don't seem to appreciate that the `href='#'` is the same for all links and hence if he "visits" 1 they all get the `visited` CSS!

Comment: Ok, so if I can't have diffrent href it's impossible?

Comment: If you use the same href you need to use one of the other CSS/JQuery solutions. Remember that for users with JS enabled, if the `onclick` handler returns `false`, then the link will not be visited. Robots will still (try to) visit the link, though, but it shouldn't be difficult to come up with an URL (you can probably just use "?dummy=1", "?dummy=2", etc. or anything else that is just ignored by your server).

Comment: Actually I'm thinking that it might not work precisely because the link is not visited... Let me think about that...

Comment: I edited my answer as the `return false` did prevent the "visited" behaviour. But there's a caveat, as it will scroll to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

No need jquery in the context . You done just in css like that

```
a:visited{

  color : purple// give any color
}
```

also see that

```
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: purple;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but when I refresh my webbrowser it dosen't work.

Comment: it will work all the time - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_visited

Comment: look here if u can: http://jsfiddle.net/c3AeN/  how do it when all links are visited?

Comment: i found that href = # is common so once you visted all href=# is colour purple chnage the href link replace # - http://jsfiddle.net/c3AeN/1/

Comment: you just done in css not jquery

Comment: Thank U Sudharsan. It's was I looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
a.do_it:visited{

  color : #800080;
}
```